# NuxtJS/apollo how to set custom header

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

How to set custom header on @nuxtjs/apollo?

```
on my nuxt.config.js
```

I have something like this

```
apollo: {
  "x-token": "hash",
  "x-auth-token": "hash",
  "x-refresh-token":  "hash",
  headers: {
  },
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      // required
      httpEndpoint: "localhost:4000"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

`nuxt.conifg.js`

```
apollo: {
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      httpEndpoint: 'localhost:4000',
      httpLinkOptions: {
        headers: {
           'x-token': 'hash',
           'x-auth-token': 'hash',
           'x-refresh-token':  'hash'
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: I also tried that one earlier, but there an error, "Converting circular structure to JSON"

The endpoint is working on fine on React.

Comment: The apollo module just got rewritten and I think this is still a release candidate and not an actual release, so this is probably a bug. What you could do is fall back to the old way by defining a path like this `default: '~/apollo/client-configs/default.js'` and then add the httplink options manually.

Comment: i see, ill try to create a separate config then import it on nuxt.config.js

Thanks.